# Чем авторское решение отличается от факультативного?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

**ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНЫЙ** [франц. facultatif] 1. Необязательный, нерегулярный. Ф-ые явления. **Ф-ые нормы (ориентировочные).**

Факультативный, от лат. facultas (facultatis) – способность, возможность.

Итак, о  **факультативном решении** мы говорим, когда  правила предоставляют нам **возможность выбора**, например: обособление обстоятельств является факультативным.

**А что такое авторское решение?**  Оно равнозначно факультативному, противопоставлено ему или где-то пресекается с ним?

Могу ли я, к примеру, сказать так:  обособление наречия здесь **не факультативное, а авторское.** Имеется в виду следующее предложение: *Поэтому, о чём тут может идти речь?*

Answer (score 2):

> Чем авторское решение отличается от факультативного?

Применительно к вопросам правописания, полагаю, ничем, кроме акцента.
И то и другое касается выбора варианта из числа двух или более не противоречащих правилам.

Но есть два существенных замечания.
Во-первых, "авторским знаком" часто называют знак, поставленный не по правилам, а вопреки им. Аналогично, когда у автора возникают проблемы с орфографией или грамматикой, его вариант называют почему-то "авторским". Полагаю, такое понимание не должно иметь места, ибо оно путает.
В качестве примера приведу известное высказывание Горького "Всему хорошему во мне я обязан книгам". Я опущу вопрос о том, действительно ли Горький написал
именно так (сейчас и это поставлено под сомнение, так как  фраза в таком виде появилась впервые в каком-то германском издании и её готовы списать на небрежность иностранцев).
Так вот эту фразу стыдливо называли "авторским вариантом", хотя налицо грамматическая ошибка.
Второе. Есть такое устоявшееся выражение "орфография/пунктуация автора". Им снабжают в газетах "письма читателей", оставленных для пущей убедительности без редактирования.  Возможно, в таком контексте оно и возможно. Но не надо переносить на понятие авторский знак.

Таким образом, различие между факультативным и авторским знаком в конечном счете заключается в том, что первый термин используется как правило тогда, когда речь идет о формулировке правил, а второй - когда разбирают уже написанное и даже изданное. Обычно это происходит, когда автор использует возможное по правилам, но необычное для данного случая пунктуационное решение. Типичный пример - "интонационная запятая".  Правила её не запрещают, но автор должен очень хорошо понимать, что знак этот - на его совести.

> Могу ли я, к примеру, сказать так: обособление наречия здесь не
> факультативное, а авторское. Имеется в виду следующее предложение:
> Поэтому, о чём тут может идти речь?

Я как-то не вижу здесь ни факультативного ни авторского. Без запятой  здесь, на мой вкус, нарушалась бы грамматика.

(+) ====

В Нацкорпусе обнаружился только один , очень древний, пример подобного построения фразы. Из трех других два имеют иную грамматику, а еще один непонятен без контекста.

> У вас ваш процесс развития и вторичного упрощения есть процесс
> фаталистический, деспотический, неизбежный… Поэтому о чем же
> хлопотать? Зачем писать… Вы ― Иеремия, плачущий над развалинами… [К.
> Н. Леонтьев. Моя литературная судьба (1875)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Не совсем, на мой взгляд по-русски, но что касается запятой, то здесь она действительно невозможна, фраза перестанет быть понимаемой даже в контексте. Так что для вопроса  о факультативности пример непригоден.

Comment: @behemothus Спасибо за ваше мнение, в вашем ответе есть полезная для меня информация.
Не очень ясно высказывание о грамматике для предложения «Поэтому, о чём тут может идти речь?». У Розенталя в правилах сказано: 5. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят слова особенно, в частности, и т. п. с присоединительным значением, то запятая после этих слов не ставится: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137   Про наречие «поэтому» информации нет, на практике же запятая ставится «факультативно», в зависимости от структуры  СПП. Но здесь не сложное предложение, а вопросительное.

Comment: Можно также представить такой вариант без запятой: «Поэтому о чем тут говорить, уже всё сказано».

Comment: @Sharon  *У Розенталя в правилах сказано* - чтобы говорить об этом правиле надо как минимум иметь здесь СПП. Если убрать "поэтому", то "о чем" - вопросительное слово, никак не подчинительный союз. Появление в такой фразе "поэтому" нарушает грамматику. Да попытка смысл ставит в тупик.

Comment: *«Поэтому о чем тут говорить, уже всё сказано»* - не вижу, что тут изменилось в смысле грамматики. Смысл доходит лучше, да вопрос риторический, но что здесь делает "поэтому" всё еще совершенно непонятно с точки зрения грамматики.

Answer (score 1):

"Факультативное" и "авторское" в данном случае никак не связаны.

*Факультативность написания* означает наличие нескольких альтернативных вариантов, которые не вызывают нарушения правил. Написание может быть факультативным *с точки зрения правил*.

*Авторская орфография и пунктуация* не имеют непосредственного отношения к правилам. Они лишь говорят, что автор написал именно так. Это было его решение. Возможно это сделано для какого-то эффекта, возможно автор использует *факультативность* того или иного правила.

А возможно это просто ошибка.

Написание всегда является авторским.

Кстати, не могу не упомянуть тот факт, что написание публикуемых текстов, как правило, является коллаборативным процессом. У подавляющего большинства опубликованных книг—множество "авторов". И написание может быть *авторским* по отношению к каждому из них.

Например, *авторское* оформление писателя может (и почти наверняка будет), после прохождения редактуры, быть заменено на *авторское* оформление редактора.

Аналогично, то или иное написание может являться *факультативным* по отношению к одному сборнику правил, но строго корректным (или строго некорректным) по отношению к другому.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Ортогональный - это, вероятно, несовместимый? У меня, правда,  немного другое мнение.   А вот неверное написание прбелов - это скорее авторская небрежность, а не авторское решение.   И еще, если позволите:  В приведенном (в вопросе) предложении обособление "поэтому" авторское или факультативное? Можно коротко,  да или нет, просто интересен ваш ответ.

Comment: Jklen, сколько же у вас лишних запятых!

Comment: @JKlen Извините, забыла задать вам вопрос по предложению: "Поэтому, о чём тут может идти речь?". У нас "поэтому" - местоименное наречие , можно ли  ли его обособлять по правилу для обстоятельственных наречий?

Comment: Быть одновременно местоименными и обстоятельственными можно, а вот можно ли обособляться по одним правилам - это вопрос. § 77. Для смыслового подчеркивания могут обособляться некоторые обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями. Условия их выделения те же, что и у обстоятельств, выраженных существительными в косвенных падежах: Вы можете привести пример с местоименным наречием (только не для уточняющих слов)? К примеру: Тогда, оставайся здесь.  Оставайся, тогда, здесь. У меня тут смысловое подчеркивание.

Comment: Две) После "в данном случае" и "примере".

Comment: Извините еще раз,  я вижу, вы и так уделили мне больше внимания, чем вам хотелось бы.  О своде правил я говорю в своем ответе, а что касается предложения «Тогда — оставайся здесь», то здесь интонационное тире, его можно использовать достаточно свободно. А вот интонационных запяттых у нас нет. Давайте так. Чтобы завершить нашу беседу, пожалуйста, подтвердите, что по общим правилам  вы допускаете постановку запятых в приведенных ранее примерах: "Тогда, оставайся здесь. Оставайся, тогда, здесь".  Тогда ваша окончательная точка зрения мне будет ясна, и я не буду больше ни о чем справшивать.

Comment: Ха-ха) Ну а точка перед кавычками подо что подпадает? ;)

Comment: "Пример", кстати, совсем не подпадает, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @JKlen Что ж, это ваш выбор. Тогда, как договорились.

Comment: Я не специалист, но это никакое не обстоятельство. В общем, не относится к тому, о чём там говорится.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за ответы. Я постараюсь коротко рассказать, как я понимаю эту тему.

1. Применительно к правилам **факультативное** решение – это достаточно точный термин, он подразумевает **наличие двух разрешенных форм письма**, из которых автор выбирает то, что ему подходит.

Слово ***авторский*** в  общем плане имеет очень широкий спектр значений, в том числе и по отношению к правилам. Здесь возможны **все три варианта**, названные в вопросе. Иногда мы считаем слова ***факультативный*** и ***авторский*** синонимами, в других случаях говорим об ***авторском*** выборе варианта письма из двух разрешенных. Но есть и третий случай, который заслуживает особого внимания: авторское решение может быть **противопоставлено** факультативному.

Факультативное написание является **нормированным**, а вот авторским можно называть ненормированное письмо. Здесь возможны разные варианты - от элементарной неграмотности до более глубокого понимания возможностей орфографической системы, но это особый разговор.

2. Далее я хочу перейти к конкретному примеру – к теме **обособления обстоятельств**. Факультативность, объявленная в начале статьи официального свода, начинает **регламентироваться** уже в тексте этих правил: чаще обособляются обороты с производными предлогами,  а вот **наречия** обособляются только некоторые и только иногда.

И не стоит этому удивляться и уж тем более надо различать **виды наречий**. К примеру, **местоименные** наречия обычно используются в уточняющих конструкциях, а **одиночные** наречия могут составлять пару «вводное слово – обстоятельство», их иногда называют **модальными** наречиями.

Кроме основного свода правил («объективного текста и обобщающего стандарта»), изложенного в одном параграфе, эти же вопросы рассматриваются **в других темах** того же свода, да еще существует полуофициальный **«Справочник по пунктуации» издательства** на портале Грамота.ру. Приведу конкретные примеры из Справочника:

АНАЛОГИЧНО, наречие. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

В ТАКОМ / ЭТОМ СЛУЧАЕ, наречное выражение. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Также не будет обособляться сочетание  В ПРИВЕДЕННОМ ВАМИ ПРИМЕРЕ,  так как оно входит в основное содержание предложения. Произносительные паузы запятыми не обозначаются, даже если их назвать смысловыми – запятыми обозначают только грамматические паузы.

**Вот такая у нас факультативность.**